# How can I start the SSRS 2016 Report Server?

Tags: ssrs-2016

I restarted my SSRS 2016 server. When I navigate to the Web Portal URL I get a "Service Unavailable - HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." message. How do I start the SSRS 2016 Report Server?

Comment: You checked that your SSRS service is started? Any error log message in windows event?

Comment: Yes. I checked and the service is running.

Comment: Did you configure the SSRS server?

Comment: I checked the SSRS server and it was returning an error: Service Unavailable - HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. There is a "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)" service that manages, executes, renders, schedules and delivers reports. It was set with an "Automatic" Startup Type. After a reboot the service was indeed running but I was still getting a 503 Service unavailable error. I found a blog that says the Startup Type needs to be "Automatic (Delayed Start)". Once I changed the Startup Type to "Automatic (Delayed Start)" and restarted the service the report server started working.